# cdecl inet_ntop(int,void const *,char *,unsigned int)" referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, inet

I am using inet_ntop in my code to get the ip address of the offline captured files. I am getting the error

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const*__cdecl inet_ntop(int,void const *,char *,unsigned int)" (?inet_ntop@@YAPBDHPBXPADI@Z) referenced in function _main`

```
    ddd.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
        //

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <ether.h>
#include <ip.h>
#include <ipnet.h>
#include <ipproto.h>
#include <tcp.h>
#include <udp.h>
#include <ethertype.h>
#include <tcpdump-stdinc.h>

using namespace std;

void PrintPacket(pcap_pkthdr * header, const u_char *data);
void PrintData(u_int startOctet, u_int endOctet, const u_char *data);
u_short get_ethertype_value(const u_char *data);
char * get_ethertype(const u_int16_t ethertype);




static u_int packetCount = 0;


#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


string file = "C:\\Users\\legendkiller\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\new.pcap"; 
char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_t * pcap = pcap_open_offline(file.c_str(), errbuff);
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
const u_char *data;
while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, &data) >= 0)
{

    PrintPacket(header, data);


    printf("Packet Details\n");


    const struct ether_header *ethernet;
    const struct ip* ipHeader;
    char sourceIp[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char destIp[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];


    ethernet = (struct ether_header*)(data);

    // Print Destination Mac Address
    printf("Dst MAC: ");
    PrintData(0,5,ethernet->ether_dhost);

    // Print Source Mac Address
    printf("Src MAC: ", ethernet->ether_shost);
    PrintData(0,5,ethernet->ether_shost);

    // Print EtherType
    u_short ethertype = ntohs(ethernet->ether_type);
    printf("Ethertype: %s (%#.4x)\n", get_ethertype(ethertype), ethertype);
    ipHeader = (struct ip*)(data + sizeof(struct ether_header));
      inet_ntop(IPH_AF_INET, &(ipHeader->ip_src), sourceIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
      inet_ntop(IPH_AF_INET, &(ipHeader->ip_dst), destIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    printf("sourceIp : %s\n", sourceIp);
    printf("destIp :%s\n",destIp);




    printf("\n\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Dude, it sounds like somebody's trying to reference a "C" function from a "C++" translation unit.  Look up "extern C".  The standard system headers should all do that for you, automagically.  Are you using them?  What the heck is "tcp.h" or "udp.h"???

Comment: @nneonneo how would a linker error be related to a header file? (hint: in no way...)

Comment: @H2CO3: if the header file declares the function `extern "C"` it would matter.

Comment: @H2C03 - in this case, a header file is *very definitely* related to the link error.  Think about it :).  And yes, "winsock.h" is good advice :)

Comment: @nneonneo yes, but aren't sockets part of libc? If so, I doubt libc headers declare functions as "extern C"...

Comment: Oh and finally, you should *really* put these functions in a separate **C** file. If there aren't any C++ inside, why name it .cpp?

Comment: `libws2_32`, actually (since this is Windows). I think those are supposed to interop properly with C++ since much Windows code is in C++.

Comment: @H2CO3: He's using `std::string`.

Comment: @nneonneo Right, didn't aperceive it. Sorry for that.

Comment: @paulsm4 no need to be rude. (flagged your comment)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this API resides `#include <ws2tcpip.h>` header, which would be pulled in if you're using `winsock2.h`.  Are you including either of these headers?

Comment: @Keith Halligan  Yes I tried using #include <ws2tcpip.h> and winsock2.h but still the same error

Comment: Let me clear it....I am using inet_ntop to convert the binary based Ip to human readable form for the offline pcap file. Included all the required headers but i think some lib is missing.... as I used "ntohs" for the mac address it was also not working on the first attempt and gave the similar error. then i used "ws2_32.lib" in linker additional includes. Now having the similar problem for this inet_ntop and cant figure it out after spending almost 10 hours..... Any help will strongly be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: @user1631771 What version of Windows are you building this on?